# Django admin. Поменять количество отображаемых полей

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Когда в Django выбираешь одну из моделей, тогда на странице отображается, с 0 до 100 объектов. Можно ли данное количество увеличить?

Comment: list_per_page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_per_page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установите, list_per_page чтобы контролировать количество элементов, отображаемых на каждой странице списка изменений администратора с разбивкой на страницы. По умолчанию это установлено на 100.

```
class RecordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 200 

admin.site.register(models.Record, RecordAdmin)
```